# jQuery datepicker problem in IE after upgrade to 1.6.1 and jQueryUI 1.8.12

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

We recently updated jQuery from 1.4.2 to 1.6.1, and jQueryUI from 1.8.4 to 1.8.12.

In our testing, we've had no serious issues excepting one:

We have a custom control that uses a datepicker and updates a dropdown of formats when a new date is selected.  Now, when you select a date you get the following error:

```
'length' is null or not an object

WebResource.axd
```

Prior to this upgrade, this was working fine in all modern browsers.  Since the upgrade, it has stopped working in IE (64-bit machine running windows 7, IE 8, compatibility mode doesn't matter) for our testers.  It still seems to work in XP.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704398/jquery-datepicker-popup-not-closing-on-select-date-in-ie8) was asked way back in '09 and it got a [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704398/jquery-datepicker-popup-not-closing-on-select-date-in-ie8/1975858#1975858).

I've tried implementing that, and it breaks the 'Update the dropdownlist' portion of the functionality.

The control is initialized by calling this function, passing in the control as $scope:

```
function InitializeCalendarDateControl($scope) {
CalendarDateControl_FirstTimeThrough = true;

$("input.date", $scope).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1850:c+5'});  

var groupedControls = $("div.CalendarDateControlCssClass[groupname!=]", $scope);


    --snip some control hiding stuff
    --snip some time format validation stuff


if (!$scope.hasClass("CalendarDateControlCssClass")) {
    $("input.hasDatepicker, input.hh, input.mm, select.dates, select.ampm", $scope).live("change", function () {
        CalendarDateControl_FirstTimeThrough = false;
        updateControls($(this));
    });

    if (groupedControls.length > 0) {
        $("div.CalendarDateControlCssClass", $scope).each(function () {
            updateControls($(this).children("input:eq(0)"));
        });
    }
} else {
    $("input.hasDatepicker, input.hh, input.mm, select.dates, select.ampm", $scope).live("change", function () {
        CalendarDateControl_FirstTimeThrough = false;
        updateControls($(this));
    });
    if (groupedControls.length > 0) {
        updateControls($scope.children("input:eq(0)"));
    }
}
}
```

The updateControls function is the function that updates the dropdown list.

Using the fix linked in the answer above, the change events don't seem to fire.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would upgrade to 1.5.2 at the moment, since there are maybe some potential break changes in 1.6+