# Difference between button.click() and button.fireEvent('click')

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does .fireEvent() not work in IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714527/why-does-fireevent-not-work-in-ie9)

Why these two statements are not synonymous?
this.button.click();
and
this.button.fireEvent('click');

When I execute the first statement, it internally calls the second statement. But when I execute the second statement, it does not call the first statement internally. Why is this?

Comment: You can't have them call each other. Else, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop where they keep calling each other.

Comment: @Joseph who said something about IE

Comment: @Amit: Can you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have them call each other. Else, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop where they keep calling each other