# Odd Javascript Error with ASP.NET and jQuery with Validation control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am getting a mysterious (to me) javascript error when I activate the jQuery-UI script that generates the DatePicker.  It works, if I am in Visual Studio and tell it to ignore the error.  The selected date is generated and tossed into the text box as desired.  But why this error?  *It only happens when there is a validation error present and involved.*

OK, here is the code.  First the asp.net page markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PickerDateTextBox" runat="server" Width="100" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="This is required"
    ControlToValidate="PickerDateTextBox"
    >
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PickerDateTextBox").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/picker.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And of course the includes are:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Don't worry, I've gotten this even with jquery 1.9.

The error is NOT within jQuery, or jQuery-UI, but in Microsoft's javascript, here:

```
var vals;
if (typeof(targetedControl.Validators) != "undefined") {
    vals = targetedControl.Validators;
}
else {
    if (targetedControl.tagName.toLowerCase() == "label") {
        targetedControl = document.getElementById(targetedControl.htmlFor);
        vals = targetedControl.Validators;
    }
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
}
ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
```

The error is thrown on the line where "i < vals.length;" occurs, and the error is:

```
Unhandled exception at line 172, column 17 in http://localhost...blah blah blah
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined
```

Again, this doesn't happen if I do NOT have a validation control there (any kind).

Any ideas what is happening and how I can fix it?

**Edited to Add:**

As @Steve-Wellens points out, when running on .NET 4.5 and jQuery 1.9.1 it runs OK.  Also on .NET 4.0.  Unfortunately I need it to work on .NET 3.5 due to server limitations (our web servers are Windows 2003, upon which .NET 4.5 cannot be installed.  I guess I could set the app to run .NET 4.0, but @Steve-Wellens has delivered the work-around so it's good to go as-is!

Comment: It seems to work with .NET 4.5, jQuery 1.9 and IE 10.

Comment: OK, maybe I've got some kind of versioning problem going on.  I see VS2012 now has Update 2.  Will update that, make sure jQuery 1.9 is going on correctly.  Although this is for a product that due to server version cannot deploy in .NET 4.5.  I need it to work in .NET 3.5.

Comment: I targeted .NET 3.5 and reproduced the problem...but I get the error when I select a date in the date picker.

Comment: Yes, that's where I get it, when I click on the image.

Comment: I can see in the script it thinks the targetedControl is the hyperlink (from the calendar) which of course has no Validators and hence the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix/hack/kludge  (add an empty onSelect handler):

```
$("#PickerDateTextBox").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    onSelect: function() {},
    buttonImage: "images/picker.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

And explanation:
[Jquery datepicker popup not closing on select date in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704398/jquery-datepicker-popup-not-closing-on-select-date-in-ie8/1975858#1975858)